# ANTLR struggling to parse integer vs quoted string

Tags: java, antlr

I'm trying to create a language using ANTLR where each line consists of an instruction, where an instruction is an opcode and any number of operands like so:

```
aaa "str1" "str2" 123
bbb 123 "str" 456
ccc
ddd
```

I have strings seemingly working OK, but integers seem to be parsed incorrectly.

Here's my complete grammar file:

```
grammar Insn;

prog: (line? NEWLINE)+;

line: instruction;
instruction: instruction_name instruction_operands?;

instruction_name: IDENTIFIER;
instruction_operands: instruction_operand instruction_operand*;
instruction_operand: ' '+ (operand_int | operand_string);

operand_int: INT;
operand_string: QSTRING;

NEWLINE : [\r\n]+;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+;
INT: '-'?[0-9]+;
QSTRING: '"' (~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n') | '\\' ('"' | '\\'))* '"';
COMMENT: ';' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I've tried multiple different INT definitions such as `INT: '-'?('0'..'9')+;` and `INT: '2';` making all the INTs in the input `2`, always resulting in an error similar to `line 1:18 extraneous input '123' expecting {' ', INT, QSTRING}`, with the line number, column and `123` integer replaced with whatever it was parsing.

Here's the parse tree generated by ANTLR's tooling as used in the ANTLR getting-started.md document.[image: parse tree]

I'm completely new to ANTLR and am not familiar with lots of terminology so please keep it simple for me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think `INT: '-'?[0-9]+;` may need an extra blank: `INT: '-'? [0-9]+;`

Comment: @DietmarHöhmann just tried it, nothing changed.

Comment: Indeed! I was wrong. The problem is one line above: `123`is recognised as `IDENTIFIER`! Because it is a valid identifier (all `INT`s are). Both of them must be distinguishable. `IDENTIFIER` should probably be something like this `IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*;`

Comment: @DietmarHöhmann thanks! I managed to take your idea and make it suit my needs by moving the `INT` definition before `IDENTIFIER` and making `instruction_name: INT | IDENTIFIER;` which seems to work for me now, I forgot to mention the requirement to keep instruction_name to be valid as an integer too. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it as it does answer the question I asked originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `123`is recognised as `IDENTIFIER` because it is a valid identifier (all `INT`s are). Both of them must be distinguishable. `IDENTIFIER` should probably be something like this `IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*;`